# How to get the value of the date.timezone directive?

Tags: datetime, timezone, php

I can see in my `phpinfo()` that my server's **Default timezone** and its **date.timezone** directive is not in sync.

[image]

I know I can get the value of the **Default timezone** by using `date_default_timezone_get()` but how can we get the value of the **date.timezone** during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the timezone with the `ini_get()` function:

```
ini_get('date.timezone');
```

By the way you should always set the default timezone at the beginning of your scripts. You could do it like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set(ini_get('date.timezone'));
```